# Why is node added to wrong Linked List?

Tags: java

I'm having an issue with part of my code where I want to split up rows that have an empty string at index 0 from those that do not.  Though only needing the index of the row and an integer of element 1 or difference between elements 1 and 0. I decided to use two linked lists to split up each type of row, but I'm getting a strange result.  Somehow a row is getting added to the wrong linked list.

```
void Splitter () {
    String[][] databaseSchedule = {
        {"", "100", "129 East Fremont St, Las Vegas, NV 89101"},
        {"", "50", "770 N Las Vegas Blvd, Las Vegas, NV 89101"},
        {"", "300", "1610 E Tropicana Ave, Las Vegas, NV 89119"},
        {"1300", "1400", "755 E Flamingo Rd, Las Vegas, NV 89119"},
        {"", "200", "4650 Aspen Ave Mt Charleston, NV 89124"},
    };
    int[] subArray = new int[2];
    List<int[]> anyTimeStart = new LinkedList<>();
    List<int[]> strictTimeStart = new LinkedList<>();

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < databaseSchedule.length; ++i) {
            if ("".equals(databaseSchedule[i][0])) {
                subArray[0] = i;
                subArray[1] = Integer.parseInt(databaseSchedule[i][1]);
                anyTimeStart.add(subArray);
            }
            else {
                subArray[0] = i;
                subArray[1] = Integer.parseInt(databaseSchedule[i][1]) -
                        Integer.parseInt(databaseSchedule[i][0]);
                strictTimeStart.add(subArray);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strictTimeStart.get(0)));
                //Prints out [3, 100] which is expected.
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strictTimeStart.get(0)));
        //Prints out [4, 200], what happened?
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        System.out.println("String cannot be converted to integer");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain *wrong list*? What is the current outcome and what is the expected outcome?

Answer (score 0):

You only have one array instance:

```
int[] subArray = new int[2];
```

which you add to both lists. Calling `list.add(subArray)` doesn't add a copy of `subArray` to the list. It adds a reference to the same array referenced by the `subArray` variable. Therefore both your lists end up containing multiple references to the same array.

Create a new array before adding to a list. For example:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < databaseSchedule.length; ++i) {
        subArray = new int[2];
        if ("".equals(databaseSchedule[i][0])) {
            subArray[0] = i;
            subArray[1] = Integer.parseInt(databaseSchedule[i][1]);
            anyTimeDuration.add(subArray);
        } else {
            subArray[0] = i;
            subArray[1] = Integer.parseInt(databaseSchedule[i][1]) -
                    Integer.parseInt(databaseSchedule[i][0]);
            strictTimeDuration.add(subArray);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strictTimeDuration.get(0)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Even better: declare `subArray` in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're always adding the same object in both your lists: `subArray`. Declare and initialize in inside the loop:

```
...
    for (int i = 0; i < databaseSchedule.length; ++i) {
        int[] subArray = new int[2];
...
    }
...
```